# Linux "connectionless" wlan

Tags: linux, wifi

I'm currently planning to do cheap wireless video transmission from mobile, battery powered devices to a base station.

To be clear, I did not do any tests so far, but because the required range will be quite large (>2000ft/600m) and by my experience on wifi I'm quite sure this won't work using a standard wifi connection using standard german wifi cards (max 100mW power). Wifi requires a two-way connection to keep associated with each other.
However, I don't really care if my device can receive data from my base station.
I can use large antennas on the receiving side (base station) but not on the device. So I thought what is not there can't break. So my intention is to send 802.11 packets without beeing connected.

How can I send and receive 802.11 frames in Linux without the network stack adding or removing any data (or even dropping the packet because it does not know how to handle it) ?

An 802.11 frame at it's lowest level consists of the following fields:

Preamble | PLCP header | MPDU (MAC PDU)

My intent is to control anything that's inside the MPDU.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By the way due to antenna reciprocity its gain will affect both the transmitted and received signal on. The abilitiy to receive signal on both devices will depend on their transmitters power levels and receivers sensitivities.

Comment: There are frames which are created solely in 80211 MAC layer. These frames will not have any upper layer protocol overhead. For example PS-Poll frame.